# How to compute ray-segment intersection in vector form?

Tags: math, computational-geometry

I'm need to compute the fact of intersection of ray and segment in one plane and the distance from ray origin to intersection point, but I very bad know computation geometry, so... how to do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segment with endpoints A and B (all vectors) has an equation:

```
P(x) = A * x + B * (1 - x)
```

where 0 <= x <= 1.

Ray with origin R and directional (unit) vector U has an equation:

```
Q(y) = R + U * y
```

where y >= 0.

You just need to solve the equation:

```
P(x) = Q(y)
```

That is, to find parameters x and y (if they exist), satisfying this (vector) equation. You will have two scalar equations and two variables to calculate. You can easily solve this linear system and then check conditions 0 <= x <= 1 and y >= 0. If these conditions are both satisfied you got a solution, otherwise there are no intersection. The y value will give you distance from the ray origin to the intersection point.

Also you have to consider many degenerate cases, for example - the ray passes via both segment endpoints etc.